# Django admin template override 'change_list' not working on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have template files located app directories like `%project%/%app%/templates`, and have had no trouble with Heroku locating other templates files. I now have an admin template at `%project%/%app%/templates/admin/%app%/%model%/change_list.html` and when I am browsing the admin pages locally the template renders fine. When I try on Heroku my template is not showing up and just the default `change_list.html` is showing.

I have no other template issues and have tried putting the templates at the root level in `%project%/templates/`.

Here is my template config:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)
```

I am also using [grappelli](http://grappelliproject.com/) if that matters.

Anyone have an idea of what could be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to load your own `change-list` template you have to add this to your admin model:

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/author/change_list.html'
    list_display = ('name','age',)
```

You will need to create the `author/change_list.html` under the `templates` directory. More information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template) in the official Django documentation page.